# Disable Checkstyle warning on public final static logger

Tags: java, logging, checkstyle

How can I suppress the ALL_CAPS naming convention warning on my following logger declaration.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

I only want to ignore above check style warning for logger. I have configured the Suppression File but I am not able to find the XML I should add in it to achieve the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override the format property, and instead of the default (`^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$`), do something like this:

```
<module name="ConstantNameCheck">
    <property name="format" value="^(([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*)|(logger))$"/>
</module>
```

so start-of-line, regular all-caps pattern or "logger", then end-of-line